# Is it possible to draw multiple 3D objects having its independent planes or axis respectively?

Tags: opengl

I am a beginner I am doing a car parking game..its a top view of a parking lot.. i need to ve a constant parking surroundings but the thing is tht when i turn my car using glRotatef functions in special key function the whole surrounding turns along the car :(

i use the transformations in the following functions

```
void keyspecial( GLint key, GLint x, GLint y )
{
if( key == GLUT_KEY_UP) // up
{

for(int i=0;i<29;i++)
vertices[i][1]+=.50;
}
if( key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
{
    for(int i=0;i<29;i++)
vertices[i][1]-=.5;
}
if(key ==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
{

    translator() ; 
rotaterl();
tran();


}
if(key ==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
{
    translator() ; 
rotaterr();
tran();

}

if(key == GLUT_KEY_F2 )
{
    translatorb() ; 
rotaterl();
 tranb();



}

if(key == GLUT_KEY_F1 )
{
    translatorb() ; 
rotaterr();
 tranb();


}

glutPostRedisplay();}
```

the translator n tranb are nothing but contains  glTranslatef(..)

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is utilise the matrix stack in your drawing code. This is what the code would look like:

```
//Transform parking lot if you want
//Draw the parking lot

glPushMatrix();
//Do transforms like glRotate, glTranslate, etc.
//Draw the car
glPopMatrix();
```

When you use glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix, any transforms within these statements will only affect what is inside them. Also, if you transformed the parking lot, then the cars would move too, as you transform the parking lot, then you push/pop afterwards. Each car will need to be pushed/popped separately so they don't transform each other.

If you wanted the parking lot transformations to be completely independent of the cars, then you'd do:

```
glPushMatrix();
//Transform and draw parking lot
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
//Transform and draw car
glPopMatrix();
```

Now the parking lot and the cars will have no effect on each other's transformations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: superMAximo@ i ll implement the above n check thnx a lot

Comment: but the problem here is i use transformation in void keyspecial( GLint key, GLint x, GLint y ) function, so i cant implement the above structure u recommended :(

Comment: Maybe store the values generated in keyspecial, and them recall them in your drawing function? I.e. store the transformations you want to apply in some variables which are passed to your car drawing function, and then push, transform using those values, draw the car, and pop.

Answer (score 0):

As SuperMaximo93 says, it's important to separate your transformation matrices, so that all objects are drawn with their own unique transformation. `glPushMatrix()` is a relatively easy way to handle this.

I should add that it's also important that you call your transformation functions (glTranslatef/Rotatef/Scalef/etc) in the correct order.

OpenGL multiplies transformation matrices in post-order (as opposed to *pre*-order). So when you call `glRotatef()`, the current matrix, *C*, is multiplied by the rotation matrix representing the `glRotate()` call, *M*, in the following way:

*C x M*

and a position (or vector), *v* transformed by the call is transformed in the following way:

*C x M x v*

This forces you to call the transformation functions in an order which may seem reverse of what should be accomplished. For example:

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
drawMyObject();
```

The effect of the code above would be that the object drawn will *first* be rotated 30 degrees CCW, *then* translated upwards on the screen by 1.0 (assuming positive is up on the y-axis), as opposed to first being translated up, then being rotated along the center of the screen by 30 degrees CCW.

Also see http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml for more documentation on this.

Comment: but the problem here is i use transformation in void keyspecial( GLint key, GLint x, GLint y ) function, so i cant implement the above structure u recommended :

Comment: Why not? This is C++, you can do *anything*. :) Note that I'm not telling you how to code; the code in my answer is merely an example of the effects of post-order matrix multiplication.